# Excel AddOLEObject function not working on window 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I write a function(C#,ASP.Net) that add ***pdf*** file into Excel sheet. It work 100% on my development environment but when I publish on window 2008 R2 server, it turn out following error. I did the same settings like my development setting. I have no idea whats going on.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Cannot
>   insert object. at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String
>   memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes,
>   MessageData& msgData) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shapes.AddOLEObject(Object ClassType,
>   Object Filename, Object Link, Object DisplayAsIcon, Object
>   IconFileName, Object IconIndex, Object IconLabel, Object Left, Object
>   Top, Object Width, Object Height) at
>   E_BOM_View.GenerateGPNApplyForm(Int32 ProjectID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out the solution for my problem. The way that I solved is need to uncheck ***Enable Protected Mode at startup*** in ***Adobe Reader XI*** (as I'm a Adobe Reader user). If your are Foxit Reader, you don't need to do anything. You can find out the checkbox from that menu ***Edit*** > ***Preferences*** > ***Security(Enchanced)*** or completed document is here http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/protected-mode-troubleshooting-reader.html